# Не получается обработать post-запрос от ajax

Tags: ajax, php, post

На сайте список городов

```
<li class="post_btn">Москва</li>
```

Пользователь кликает по определенному городу и это значение отправляется post-запросом на сервер. Задача: как только сервер получает новое значение, происходит выборка из базы, с учетом нового города. На сайте в поле "Ваш город.." меняется значение города и выводится табличка предложений по данному городу.

```
if (isset($_POST["city"])) {
  $city = $_POST["city"];
  select_db_function();
  }
```

Вот как отправляются данные:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".post_btn").click(function() {
     city= $(this).text();
  $.post("/lending2/index.php", {city: city});
  });
});
```

Но на сайте не происходит никаких изменений. Сама функция `select_db_function()` рабочая, потому что когда город отправляется через форму `input` - все отрабатывает. Не могу понять в чем проблема, прошу помощи.

Comment: @sof_ka, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: А что вы возвращаете в ответе? POST-запросом данные ушли, обработались, надо бы результат вернуть что ли... Да и обработать ответ в JS тоже не помешает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А где же функция, которая обрабатывает ответ сервера?

```
$.post("__url__",
    { __данные__},
    function(result) {
       /*
          result - данные, которые отдаёт сервер
          Здесь их надо куда-то вывести
        */
    }      
);
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать функцию, которая обрабатывает ответ от сервера? Необходимо в содержимое блока <div id="status">Ваш город..</div>  вставить город.
Попробовала вот так, но не получилось:
function(result){
          $("#status").html(result);
 }

Comment: А должно было получиться..

Пользуйтесь отладчиком: 

для Firefox - дополнение Firebug, 

в остальных - Ctrl + Shift + I

Повторю вопрос: что возвращает файл /lending2/index.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Зачем так мудрить. В jQuery есть функция load();

Работает так

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".post_btn").click(function() {
         city= $(this).text();
         $('#status').load("/lending2/index.php", {city: city});
      });
    });
```

//в файле index.php находите нужные записи в БД и просто выводите html код с названием нужного города

```
    echo '<div class="city">ваш код</div>';
```

функция load() в нашем примере загружает html код полученный с сервера внутрь блока с айди status

в итоге получается так

```
     <div id="status"><div class="city">ваш код</div></div>
```